# How can I load XRegExp only with a few addons?

Tags: javascript, xregexp

I've searched XRegExp's [web site](http://xregexp.com/), and the GitHub [readme](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp). The only examples there load `xregexp-all.js`, which is exactly what I don't want to do because it loads all the addons. Searching on SO, I found examples like this:

```
<script src="xregexp.js"></script>
<script src="addons/unicode-base.js"></script>
<script src="addons/unicode-categories.js"></script>
```

But trying the above just causes `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`.

How can I load XRegExp with only some of its addons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage you show with `script` may have worked with earlier versions of XRegExp but it is now obsolete, and the new usage does not seem to be documented anywhere.

You can load `xregexp-all.js` with a `script` tag because it has a [UMD wrapper](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) at the very beginning of the file which allows this usage. However, if you look at the *transpiled* addon files that are shipped with XRegExp, you'll see code like this in each addon:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

exports.default = function (XRegExp) {
// ...
};
```

This tells you two things. One is that the addons are modules, period. They do not have UMD wrappers so loading them with `script` won't work. Secondly, the addons export one thing: a function. As the name of the argument suggests, you need to pass to it the XRegExp library itself so that the addon can install itself. A further clue is found in the `src/index.js` [source](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/f4fb95fa492b282f055f0c8de7669fab76bc6ae0/src/index.js) in the repository. It contains:

```
import XRegExp from './xregexp';

import build from './addons/build';
import matchRecursive from './addons/matchrecursive';
import unicodeBase from './addons/unicode-base';
import unicodeBlocks from './addons/unicode-blocks';
import unicodeCategories from './addons/unicode-categories';
import unicodeProperties from './addons/unicode-properties';
import unicodeScripts from './addons/unicode-scripts';

build(XRegExp);
matchRecursive(XRegExp);
unicodeBase(XRegExp);
unicodeBlocks(XRegExp);
unicodeCategories(XRegExp);
unicodeProperties(XRegExp);
unicodeScripts(XRegExp);

export default XRegExp;
```

After installing XRegExp with `npm`, this is what I use in a project of mine (which must run as-is on ES5 engines) where I want to load XRegExp with only some Unicode addons and nothing else:

```
var XRegExp = require("xregexp/lib/xregexp");
var base = require("xregexp/lib/addons/unicode-base");
var blocks = require("xregexp/lib/addons/unicode-blocks");
var categories = require("xregexp/lib/addons/unicode-categories");

base(XRegExp);
blocks(XRegExp);
categories(XRegExp);
```

This code works in Node and is also properly processed by Webpack for use in the browser.