# Matching word border \b in Unicode

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, xregexp

Using XRegExp, [this reply in GitHub](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/issues/228#issuecomment-811478498) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950225/2725810), I am trying to match word border `\b` in Unicode:

```js
XRegExp = require('xregexp/lib/xregexp')
base = require('xregexp/lib/addons/unicode-base')
base(XRegExp)
XRegExp.addToken(
  /\\b/,
  () => String.raw`(?:(?<=\p{L}\p{M}*)(?!\p{L}\p{M}*)|(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*)(?=\p{L}\p{M}*))`,
  {flag: 'A'}
);
console.log(XRegExp.exec("ааа бб вв", XRegExp(/\bбб\b/), "uA"))
```

The output is `null`. What am I missing?